# What is the effect of balanced class weights on logistic regression coefficients?

Tags: logistic, python, regression-coefficients, scikit-learn

I'm specifically using `sklearn`'s `LogisticRegression` on my unbalanced dataset, which has around 97% negative responses and 3% positive responses.  I'm primarily interested in interpretation and figuring out which predictors are the most important for my responses.  I've tried using `statsmodels` but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to weight the classes.

I performed `LogisiticRegression` with and without class weighting, and compared the coefficients.  Below is a distribution plot of the difference between coefficients with and without weighting.

[image: diff plot]

For reference, here is a distribution plot of the without weighting coefficients (the weighted coefficients plot looks similar).

[image: without weighting]

My understanding is that the cost function is changed so that it is costlier to make incorrect predictions on the minority class.  What I'm wondering is how will this effect regression coefficients when compared to running a logistic regression without class balancing?  Are weighted coefficients more correct?

Comment: What's the rationale for weighting the classes?  Logistic regression does not make predictions that can be interpreted as "correct" or "incorrect", it's predictions are conditional probabilities.  If you balance the classes (which I do not think you should do in this situation), you will change the intercept term in your regression since all the predicted probabilities need to change according to the new weighted marginal distribution of y, but it will not change the other coefficients in expectation (so for a large enough data set, you will only see the intercept change).

Comment: My rationale comes from when I examine the confusion matrix.  The model is predicting mostly negative responses and predicting hardly any positive responses; but when I weight the number of positive responses increases.  I'm primarily concerned with inference, but thought that prediction metrics would be a good way to evaluate the model's performance to see if the inference was useful.

Comment: So, your model (the logistic regression) is *not* predicting negative and positive.  It's predicting probabilities, and you've applied some rule for converting those probabilities into negative and positive votes.  If you're interested in inference, the confusion matrix is just a distraction, it's irrelevent.  You don't *need* the rule to convert the probabilities into votes!  You're much more interested in the quality of your probabilistic predictions, and if those are of sufficient quality, then your model is useful for inference.

Comment: That makes sense about the predictions; each prediction is a probability of a positive event.  I'm confused about assessing quality of probabilistic predictions, how would I go about that?  My first instinct is to set some sort of threshold (for example 0.03) to separate into negative and positive votes, but this sounds similar to what `sklearn` is doing already.

Comment: That's what the concept of a "proper scoring rule" is about, they measure the concordance of probabilities and outcomes.  The log-loss used in a logistic regression is an example of such a scoring rule.  So the idea is to evaluate your modeling decisions on the basis of the log-loss of your model.  If you'd like to threshold, you really want someway to average out the effect of the individual thresholds, so something like AUC is appropriate there.

Comment: I'll take this away and give it a shot.  Thank you for your help!